# Cannot set Title Text Attributes of UIBarButtonItem for Highlighted state

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

During customization stage I was trying to set the title attributes of `UIBarButtonItem` instances used in the app for both states: `UIControlStateNormal` and `UIControlStateHighlighted`.

For the `.Normal` button's state the following code works fine:

```
barButton.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.greenColor(), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(18.0)], forState: .Normal)
```

However, if I change the state parameter to `.Highlighted` the code has no effect. Firstly I thought maybe it's something wrong with the current app so I created a new project from scratch with just one toolbar and one `UIBarButtonItem` but the issue is still here.

Even setting the title attributes for all items by using the appearance proxy has no effect so the next code does nothing:

```
// Has no effect
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor(), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(28.0)], forState: .Highlighted)

// This one has no effect too  
UIBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.greenColor(), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(28.0)], forState: .Highlighted)
```

Am I missing something or is it Apple's bug? The documentation doesn't mention any cautions regarding `UIBarButtonItem` title attributes for highlighted states.

Comment: Did you manage to find solution to this? Seems it does not work anymore.

Answer (score -1):

Please check this . Hope it works for you

https://github.com/shemona-ios/barButtontextChange

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, but here are two issues with your code: 1) The button's font doesn't change 2) If I add `UIToolBar` to the screen bottom and then add `UIBarButtonItem` to it this code doesn't work completely (I mean, neither color nor font changes). For .Normal state it works perfectly fine though.

Comment: Even if the suggested link would answer the question, you should still put the relevant parts of it in your answer.